# Having trouble updating DOM based on boolean value in my scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, boolean

I'm trying to create and 'edit' mode for my application on the Manage Users page. I have every users values (such as name, email, etc) inside of an `<input>` tag with the `readonly` attribute. I have a button at the top of the page called "Edit Mode". When that edit mode is clicked, I would like the admin to be able to then click on the input field and change it. I am able to successfully toggle the `readonly` attribute on click BUT I only want that feature to happen when `editing == true` but for some season it seems that the DOM is never sensing when the editing boolean has been changed. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var editing = false;
 $(".edit-mode-toggle").click(function(){
   editing = true;
 });

if(editing){
 $("user-block input").click(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
 });
}
$(".user-block input").blur(function(){
    $(this).attr("readonly", true);
  })
});
```

Again I would only like to `removeAttr` when the `".edit-mode-toggle"` button is clicked and changes the `editing` variable to `true`. My current output is that when I click that button to toggle the boolean, I'm not able to execute my editing because the DOM hasn't seen the boolean has changed. Anyone know what might be going on. Im sure ill *derp* once I find a solution. I'm just drawing blanks here. Strictly jQuery by the way, I know this can be easily done with Angular or some other 3 way data binding framework but I want to avoid using those. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Dom only runs that `if(editing)` condition at load time, you want to move that part into your `click` function.

```
$("user-block input").click(function(){
    if(editing){
        $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
    }
});
```

Also, you need to define the `var editing` outside of the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
var editing = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
//other stuff
})
```

Comment: Won't he have a scope issue with the editing variable? Should move all the click handlers into document ready or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code because you are attaching the click events in the page load, and the second condition in the IF statement will always get attached because 'editing' variable is always set to false in the page load.

to fix it you have to make the variable 'editing' a global variable

```
 var editing = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".edit-mode-toggle").click(function(){
   editing = true;
 });


 $("user-block input").click(function(){
    if(editing){
       $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
    }else {
      $(this).attr("readonly", true);
         }
     });
} 
});
```